# Python: numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Tags: numpy, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations using ode solver in scipy.integrate. My problem is, I am getting 'singular matrix' error when my matrix is not supposed to be singular. The main issue is when I am trying to find the inverse of the matrix B in my code below. In the code below B is 3x3 matrix, A is 3x1 matrix and U is 3x1 matrix as well! 
How can I remedy this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math
import parameter_projection as pp
from scipy.integrate import ode
import sympy as sm
c=10
k,k1,k2,k3=10,9,8,7
eta=2.5
gamma,gamma1,gamma2=2,3,10
a=[]
for i in range(30):
    a.append(i)
a=np.array(a)

def aero(t,Y):
    V,alpha,beta,p,q,r,phi,theta=Y[0],Y[1],Y[2],Y[3],Y[4],Y[5],Y[6],Y[7]
    sg=np.cos(alpha)*np.cos(beta)*np.sin(theta)-np.sin(beta)*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)-np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta)*np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)
    smcg=np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*np.sin(theta)+np.cos(beta)*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)-np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)
    cmcg=np.sin(theta)*np.sin(alpha)+np.cos(alpha)*np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta)
    #error
    ev=V-np.sin(t)
    ebeta=beta-np.sin(t)
    etheta=theta-np.sin(t)
    ethetad=q*np.cos(phi)-r*np.sin(phi)-np.cos(t)
    sv,sbeta,stheta=ev,ebeta,etheta+ethetad 
    s=np.array([[sv],[sbeta],[stheta]])
    A=np.array([[-a[1]*V**2*np.sin(beta)-a[2]*V**2*np.sin(beta)-a[4]*np.sin(gamma)-np.cos(t)],[p*np.sin(alpha)-r*np.cos(alpha)+a[16]*V+a[15]*smcg-np.cos(t)],[ethetad+np.cos(phi)*a[10]*p*r+np.cos(phi)*a[6]*(r**2-p**2)+np.cos(phi)*a[20]*V**2-np.cos(phi)*a[21]*sg+-q*np.sin(phi)*p-q*np.sin(phi)*q*np.sin(phi)*np.tan(theta)-q*np.sin(phi)*r*np.cos(phi)*np.tan(theta)-np.sin(phi)*a[11]*p*q+a[12]*q*r-a[13]*V**2+r*np.cos(phi)*p+r*q*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(phi)*np.tan(theta)+(r*np.cos(phi))**2*np.tan(theta)-np.cos(t)]])
    B=np.array([[a[0]*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(beta),a[7]*np.sin(beta),a[0]*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta)],[-a[9]*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(beta)/V,a[22]*np.cos(beta)/V,-a[9]*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta)/V],[a[29]*np.cos(phi),a[26]*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*np.cos(phi)-a[27]*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(alpha),-a[25]*np.cos(phi)]])
    C=np.linalg.inv(B)*A
    U=(C-np.linalg.inv(B)*k*s-np.linalg.inv(B)*eta*np.tanh(s))
    Vdot=a[0]*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*U[0]-a[1]*V**2*np.cos(beta)-a[2]*V**2*np.sin(beta)-a[3]*sg+a[7]*np.sin(beta)*U[1]+a[0]*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta)*U[2]
    alphadot=q-(p*np.cos(alpha)+r*np.sin(alpha))*np.sin(beta)/np.cos(beta)+a[4]*V-a[14]*cmcg-a[8]*np.sin(alpha)*U[0]/V+a[8]*np.cos(alpha)*U[2]/V
    betadot=p*np.sin(alpha)-r*np.cos(alpha)+a[16]*V+a[17]*smcg-a[9]*np.cos(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*U[0]/V+a[22]*np.cos(beta)*U[1]/V-a[9]*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*U[2]/V
    pdot=a[5]*q*r+a[17]*p*q+a[18]*V**2-a[19]*smcg+a[23]*U[0]-a[28]*U[2]+a[24]*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta)*U[1]
    qdot=a[10]*p*r+a[6]*(r**2-p**2)+a[20]*V**2-a[21]*sg+a[29]*U[0]-a[25]*U[2]+a[26]*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta)*U[1]
    rdot=a[11]*p*q-a[12]*q*r+a[13]*V**2+a[27]*np.cos(alpha)*U[2]
    phidot=p+q*np.sin(phi)*np.tan(theta)+r*np.cos(phi)*np.tan(theta)
    thetadot=q*np.cos(phi)-r*np.sin(phi)
    return[Vdot,alphadot,betadot,pdot,qdot,rdot,phidot,thetadot] 

y0=[0.01,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.1]
t0=0
V=[]
alpha=[]
beta=[]
p=[]
q=[]
r=[]
phi=[]
theta=[]
t=[]
r=ode(aero).set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf',nsteps=1e10)
r.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
t1=10
dt=.01
while r.successful() and r.t<t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    V.append(r.y[0])
    alpha.append(r.y[1])
    beta.append(r.y[2])
    p.append(r.y[3])
    q.append(r.y[4])
    r.append(r.y[5])
    phi.append(r.y[6])
    theta.append(r.y[7])
    t.append(r.t)
V=np.array(V)
alpha=np.array(alpha)
beta=np.array(beta)
p=np.array(p)
q=np.array(q)
r=np.array(r)
phi=np.array(phi)
theta=np.array(theta)
plt.plot(t,V)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your initial values with `beta=phi=0` and additionally `a[0]=0` from setting `a[k]=k`¸ your matrix `B` has a first line of zeros in the first step. Which makes a singular matrix.

Changing the test data to `a[i]=i+1` removes this error but gives immediately a new error

```
rv_cb_arr is NULL
Call-back cb_fcn_in___user__routines failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odeint-LA-singular_so45165407.py", line 60, in <module>
      r.integrate(r.t+dt)
```

which is probably because all your `dot` variables are still arrays, so the returned derivatives vector is a list of `np.array` of size 3 each.

The first speculation here is that you mistakenly believe that `*` is the matrix product. This only applies if you construct the objects as `np.matrix`. With `np.array` use the `dot` for matrix-vector products and `np.linalg.solve` instead of the product with the inverse.

And indeed that is the case, use the following lines instead

```
    C = np.linalg.solve(B,A)
    U = C-np.linalg.solve(B,k*s - eta*np.tanh(s))
```

After that you find that you use the variable name `r` both for the component array and for the ODE solver. Repairing that you still get that the step size becomes too small.

---

*(add jul/19)* Using as per comments the variant

```
    U = -C-np.linalg.solve(B,k*s - eta*np.tanh(s))
```

I changed the integration loop to

```
t0=0.
y0=[0.01,0.2,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.1]
names = [ "V", "alpha", "beta", "p", "q", "r", "phi", "theta" ]

sol = [ [yy] for yy in y0 ]
t=[t0]
solver=ode(aero).set_integrator('dopri5',nsteps=1e3)
solver.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
t1=3
dt=5e-3
for t1 in range(1,11):
    if not solver.successful(): break;
    while solver.successful() and solver.t<t1:
        solver.integrate(solver.t+dt)
        for k in range(8): sol[k].append(solver.y[k]);
        t.append(solver.t)
        print "step"
    print len(t)

    for k in range(8):
        plt.subplot(4,2,k+1)
        plt.plot(t,sol[k])
        plt.ylabel(names[k])
    plt.show()
```

where the automated treatment of the solution components makes for better code and a plot is produces whenever `t` passes an integer value. The final graph is

[image]

with the singularity in `alpha` occurring at `t=3.292894674` with widely unstable values in `alphadot` varying from `-1.2e06` to `+2.9e06` with variations in the size of `1e-09` in time.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, I changed the solution name from r to s however now the step size is getting very small. I am still not able to get the graph.

Comment: Set `dt=1e-8` and also plot `alpha` to see that its derivative goes to infinity, that is, `alpha` behaves similar to `sqrt(t_sing-t)` where the singular point is at `t_sing = 4.50321260794985854e-06`. It is not immediately visible what is driving that behavior.

Comment: Hi! LutzL actually there was an error in the code, I changed the expression of U to -C-np.linalg.solve(B,ks-etanp.tanh(s)). Also I think that there will be a plus sign instead of minus between k*s and eta*np.tanh(s).
 However now it takes so much time to run the code, in fact it is running for past 5-10 mins!

Comment: Yes, that changes the point of the singularity. For progress reporting print `t` (and other values) in the derivatives function to see the internal steps or just in the integration loop. Advance `t1` in integer steps 1,2,3,... to get some graphical output to see how much the solution oscillates and how sharp the turns are which drives the internal step size down.

Comment: Hi! @LutzL
First of all, thanks a lot for getting the graphs, actually, I was trying to implement sliding mode control on thrust vectored aerial vehicles. Now, when I tried to run the code here in my system, it took like forever! I mean I started running the code at 8am and it ran all the way till 6 in the evening when I was leaving. 
Also, the V,beta and theta should more or less behave like sin(t) assymptotically. I can see in your graph that V and beta somewhat behave like sin(t), however theta does not. What can be the issue? And I also see, that it stops right after 3 seconds?

Comment: When I run the code I get similar graphs as you've got above, except that the integration stops at 0.37. U have nsteps=1e5 and dt=5e-3. The graphs that are coming out are also incorrect.

Comment: The programming problems are solved, the integration runs until some singularity. Questions on the correctness of the ODE derivatives function or the modelling in general should be asked at the scicomp, math or physics portals of stackexchange.com, then with some background on the derivation of the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input LutzL! I am modifying my system in order to make it more manageable and less uglier..:p